# Flash can't access XML files when running under Localhost

Tags: visual-studio-2010, flash, apache-flex, localhost, iis-express

We have a Flex/Flash application that loads information from XML files created by a .NET application. It works fine under IIS but when I try to run it from Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 using the ASP.NET Development Server, the Flex/Flash app isn't loading the information. I brought up Fiddler and am able to see that there's an error occurring when the Flash tries to access the XML:

[Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80

I've turned off my Firewall but that didn't help. So, I'm not sure where the block is occurring. Any thoughts?

[Update: switched from Asp.NET Development Server to IIS Express and am still getting the exact same error.]
[Update2: I've verified that the XML file the Flash is trying to reach comes up fine in the browser: http://localhost:63318/ProductDetailsXML.aspx?ProductId=71]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have to do with it being served off of a specific port (not 80). How is your application requesting the XML file? According to your Fiddler log, it's trying port 80, but your site is running on port 63318.

Comment: Great catch Neil. I've asked the Flash developer if there's anything he can do about using the current port. Is the port likely to be hard-coded in the Flash? Is there anything we can do without editing the Flash/Flex app to make it use the port it's being served from?

Comment: You'll have to select a port (just use the one that's already assigned) and set it as a "specific port" in the Visual Studio project pages just to be sure it won't change. Then, depending on how the Flash/Flex app is generating the URL to the XML file, you may need to send the port number to the Flash developer or send it to the Flash in some way (querystring, config file, etc.)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this URL will not be the same when pushing to a staging or live environment.